# Twisted, get answer from nickserv

Tags: python, twisted

I'm writing an IRC-Bot using twisted which authenticates against NickServ like this:

```
msg('NickServ', 'identify nickname password')
```

Now I want to check if the authentication succeeded. I was expecting to get the answer from `NickServ` in `privmsg`(`self`, `user`, `channel`, `message`) but this doesnt work.

How do I get the Answer from `NickServ`?